# how can I scatter a small matrix in bigger matrix using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

I have a matrix with size 28x28 but for 49999 samples (it means `w_expand=np.zeros((49999,28,28),dtype='float32')`) I also have a smaller matrix with random values (`wt_random=np.random.randint(2, size=(49999,4,4))`) now, I want to divide the first matrix into 7x7 blocks and put each element of the second matrix in middle pixel of 7x7 blocks. if it was only one matrix I know what should I do, but for this example, I do not know how can I do this. could you please help me how can I do this with python. I also have another question. if I want to expand small matrix to large matrix what should I do? this means I divide the first matrix to 7x7 blocks and then all pixels of each 7x7 blocks have the value of each pixel of the smaller matrix. ( the first 7x7 block have the value of the first pixel of 4x4 matrix)I am not familiar with python more. Thanks.
I used this loop,

```
w_expand=np.zeros((49999,28,28),dtype='float32')
wv_expand=np.zeros((9999,28,28),dtype='float32')
wt_random=np.random.randint(2, size=(49999,4,4))
wt_random=wt_random.astype(np.float32)
wv_random=np.random.randint(2, size=(9999,4,4))
wv_random=wv_random.astype(np.float32)
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        w_expand[:,(i)*7+3,(j)*7+3]=wt_random[:,i,j]
        wv_expand[:,(i)*7+3,(j)*7+3]=wv_random[:,i,j]
```

I think it works, right? can we do this without loop? but I could not solve my second problem about tiling one pixel of smaller matrix to part of bigger matrix

Comment: Does `w_expand[:, 3::7, 3::7] = wt_random` do what you want?

Comment: sorry, I'm a very beginner in Python. Does your code mean start from 3 with step length 7 the same as the loop?

Comment: could you please guide me for my second question. expanding each pixel of 4x4 matrix to a7x7 block of larger image?

Comment: Yes and `wt_random.repeat(7, 2).repeat(7, 1)`.